Distribution of relaxation time in a stretched exponential function
I'm fitting a stretched exponential function to a saturation recovery experiment, of the following form:
$$
I(t)=I_0 \left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{t}{T_1}\right)^\beta\right)
$$
Where $ \beta $ ranges from 0.5 to 1 and represents the distribution of $ T_1 $ values.
After fitting, I'd like to somehow visualize the distribution of $T_1$ values for the $\beta$ I got.
Any idea how to do that?

There are some formatting problems in the equation. Why not plot the $t$-dependence for different values of $\beta$?

Thanks for the comment. I made some edits to hopefully clear some things up. I get a certain $\beta$ that represents a distribution of $T_1$ values. How do I visualize this distribution?

I am not sure that I understand you - the whole equation represents a distribution, $\beta$ is just a parameter. It looks to me like a CDF of Weibull distrribution, but I am not familiar with the physical context.

The equation represents the buildup of signal in a saturation-recovery experiment, which is an NMR technique used to obtain the $T_1$ relaxation in a sample.
In samples dominated by one relaxation time, $\beta$ would equal 1, which would make it a simple exponential buildup, and the distribution of $T_1$ values should look like a delta function at the value of $T_1$.
For a $\beta$ of, say 0.7, there would be a distribution of $T_1$ values in the sample, corresponding to nuclei in different environments relaxing at different rates.
What I want, is to plot this distribution.

Have you checked the link that I provided above? It already contains visualizations. The only difference is the parameters choice ($\beta$ vs. $1/\lambda$)

It's similar, but not quite the same. Unless I'm missing something.

The cumulative distribution function (cdf) is the same: $F(x)=1-e^{(x/\lambda)^k}$ up to notation/parametrization. And since you speak of a buildup of signal, you probably do need the cdf, rather than the probability density (pdf).

Can you joint to your question a representative example (numerical data, not graphical).
